# Display data on table by custom index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have data something like

```
[
  {
   date: '20 Apr',
   maths: [70, 80.5, 100],
   science: [25, 20.1, 30]
  },
  {
   date: '21 Apr',
   maths: [64, 76, 80],
   science: [21, 25, 27]
  },
];
```

I want to display the data inside table with custom labels for subjects, so the output table I want is like this

```
date   |      maths      |     science
       | min | val | max | min | val | max
20 Apr | 70  | 80.5| 100 | 25  | 20.1| 30
21 Apr | 64  | 76  | 80  | 21  | 25  | 27
```

The code I have tried can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdfzyx). Is this possible to do it or is there any way I should restructure the data to have the desired output.

Comment: That structure looks good for your proposed output, but it doesn't seem to match what's in your pen?

Comment: @Nick I have transformed the data into another form, check `dataSource` variable in the console it has the same structure  I used in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The default markup contains two heading rows and the first heading contains the "Date" cell.
- Next, using the first mark object create the subject headings and "min", "val" & "max" sub headings.
- Then loop over the subjects and fill the table body.

```js
const marks = [
  { date: "20 Apr", maths: [70, 80.5, 100], science: [25, 20.1, 30] },
  { date: "21 Apr", maths: [64, 76, 80], science: [21, 25, 27] },
];

const table = document.getElementById("table");
const tableBody = document.getElementById("table-body");
const tableHeader = document.getElementById("table-header");
const tableSubHeader = document.getElementById("table-sub-header");

if (marks[0]) {
  const { date, ...subs } = marks[0];
  Object.keys(subs).forEach((sub) => {
    const th = document.createElement("th");
    th.textContent = sub;
    th.setAttribute("colspan", 3);
    tableHeader.appendChild(th);
    ["min", "val", "max"].forEach((subheading) => {
      const th = document.createElement("th");
      th.textContent = subheading;
      th.setAttribute("scope", "col");
      tableSubHeader.appendChild(th);
    });
  });
}

marks.forEach((mark) => {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  const { date, ...subs } = mark;
  const th = document.createElement("th");
  th.textContent = date;
  th.setAttribute("scope", "row");
  tr.appendChild(th);
  Object.keys(subs).forEach((sub) => {
    const [min, val, max] = subs[sub];
    tr.innerHTML += `<td>${min}</td><td>${val}</td><td>${max}</td>`;
  });
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header"><th rowspan="2" scope="col">Date</th></tr>
    <tr id="table-sub-header"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The second row should be in 21 Apr

Comment: @Viira Fixed! There was a typo in the code, it's difficult to code right on SO :P

Comment: @Viira I've updated my answer, please have a look!

Comment: Oops.. sorry I was afk I'll try this with my original code and get back to you. please wait

Comment: It works almost the same but do you know why it appends twice

Comment: @Viira Sorry I didn't get that, append twice what?

Comment: https://imgur.com/4m2cAkf please see the screenshot here

Comment: The dataset is repeating

Comment: @Viira Hmh, It's shouldn't happen ideally. Check if you're somehow doing the looping twice.

Comment: I've fixed it. Thanks for your extraordinary solution.